# Minimal solution of $\int_{R^n}|\nabla u(x)|^2dx$ on $A_R = \{ u \in Lip(R^n ) : u(x) \ge 1, |x| \le 1 \wedge u(x) = 0, |x| \ge R\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm trying to find the solution of $$  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla u(x)|^2dx$$  on $$ A_R = \{ u \in Lip(\mathbb{R}^n ) : u(x) \ge 1, |x| \le 1 \wedge u(x) = 0, |x| \ge R\} $$ for $n\ge 1$ and $R> 1$ minimizing the integral.

I was able to prove the solution needs to be radial and computet the EL equation (where $\lambda=\int\dots \int r^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-2}sin^{n-1-k}d\theta d\phi_1\dots d\phi_{n-2}$ comes from the change of variables from cartesian to spherical)
$$div(\lambda \varphi'(r)r^{n-1})=0$$

Now this tells me that $$ \lambda\varphi'(r)r^{n-1}=\kappa\iff$$$$ \varphi(r)=\frac{\kappa}{\lambda(2-n)}r^{2-n}+\rho\wedge =\frac{\kappa}{\lambda}ln(r)+\rho\wedge= \frac{\kappa}{\lambda}r+\rho.$$

But now I don't know how to include the conditions on the boundary and morover most of this functions are not continuous in 0 as they should.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use the solution from EL only between 1 and R.

We have the solutions
$$ \lambda\phi'(r)r^{n-1}=\kappa\iff$$$$ \phi(r)=\frac{\kappa}{\lambda(2-n)}r^{2-n}+\rho\wedge \frac{\kappa}{\lambda}ln(r)+\rho\wedge \frac{\kappa}{\lambda}r+\rho$$ respectively for $n>2,\; n=2,\; n=1$.\ We now need to impose the "boundary" conditions remembering that we only require this function in the set $\{x|1\le|x|\le R\}$ where they are all well defined and we get the following three systems of equations for different n.

$$n=1\Rightarrow \begin{cases}\phi(1)=\frac{\kappa}{\lambda}+\rho=1\wedge \phi(R)=\frac{R\kappa}{\lambda}+\rho=0\end{cases}\Rightarrow \phi(r)=\frac{1}{1-R}\left(r-R\right)$$
    $$n=2\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
\phi(1)=\frac{\kappa}{\lambda}ln(1)+\rho=1\\
\phi(R)=\frac{R\kappa }{\lambda}ln(R)+\rho=0
\end{cases}\Rightarrow \phi(r)=\frac{ln\left(r\right)}{ln\left(\frac{1}{R}\right)}+1 ;$$
    $$ 
n>2\Rightarrow\begin{cases}\phi(1)=\frac{\kappa}{\lambda(2-n)}+\rho=1 \quad
\phi(R)=\frac{R^{2-n}\kappa }{\lambda(2-n)}+\rho=0
\end{cases}\Rightarrow \phi(r)=\frac{1}{1-R^{2-n}}\left(r^{2-n}-R^{2-n}\right) ;$$
Anyway the general solution will be
$$ \varphi(r)=\begin{cases}
1&\Leftarrow 0\le r\le 1\\
\phi(r)&\Leftarrow 1\le r\le R\\
0&\Leftarrow r\le R;
\end{cases}$$.